# SSIS Script Component - Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=x' or its dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, script-component, ssdt-2017

I tried many steps for this "***Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.***"

After i installed Newtonsoft.Json latest version (13.0.1) and excute my program from SSIS my script component Newtonsoft property become like this image

[image]

How to solve this error in Script Component SSIS - "*Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies.*"

Comment: Not sure it helps, but I had a similar issue when I installed a library from nuget that depends on Newtonsoft.Json, for some reason the reference to Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.1 has been added the same way as in your screenshot, but the dll library file itself (that has a version 13.0.0.0) hasn't been added to the project. I had to install Newtonsoft.Json directly from nuget.
How do you install it?

Comment: Same, i also installed directly from nugget. When i execute the task the version become to 0.0.0.0